# Вычисление с помощью функции пользователя

Tags: c++, математика

[image: Задание]

Должно вычисляться выражение, что на картинке, но что-то делаю не так.Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
double mathFunc(double a, double v);
int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    double x, z, b, y;
    double bPlus2 = 2 + b;
    double xPlusY = x + y;
    cout << "Укажіть аргумент x: ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Укажіть аргумент b: ";
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Укажіть аргумент y: ";
    cin >> y;
    z = (log(mathFunc(2, x)) + log(mathFunc(2.7, y))) / fabs(log(mathFunc(bPlus2, (xPlusY))));
    cout << "Результат z = " << z;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
double mathFunc(double a, double v)
{
    log(v, a) = log(v)/log(a)
}
```

Comment: двоичный и натуральные логарифмы есть в стандартной библиотеке, так что в числителе можно попроще вычислять, а функция mathFunc у вас ни чего не возвращает так что у вас будет ошибка компиляции

Comment: и еще логарифм вы еще раз от готового логарифма после фии mathFunc берете

Answer (score 2):

```
double x, z, b, y;
double bPlus2 = 2 + b;
double xPlusY = x + y;
```

И что вы хотите получить тут, кроме мусорных значений? Вы же еще не ввели числа - что вы суммируете?!!

На что вы рассчитывали тут:

```
log(v, a) = log(v)/log(a)
```

? Если будет написано `решить x+a=b`, вы так и напишете в коде - `x+a=b`?

Вот все ваше решение:

```
int main()
{
    double x, y, b;
    cout << "Укажiть аргумент x: ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Укажiть аргумент b: ";
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Укажiть аргумент y: ";
    cin >> y;

    double z = (log2(x)+log(y))/fabs(log(x+y)/log(2+b));
    cout << "Результат: " << z << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

В плюсах (да и в многих других языках) нельзя закладываться на значение переменных, если им ещё не присвоили значение. Поэтому, конструкции

```
double bPlus2 = 2 + b;
double xPlusY = x + y;
```

хоть и выглядят интересно, но они ничего толкового не сделают - переменные x,y,b будут известны чуточку позже.

Найдите 100 отличий:)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
double mathFunc(double a, double v);
int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    double x, z, b, y;

    cout << "Вкажіть аргумент x: ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Вкажіть аргумент b: ";
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Вкажіть аргумент y: ";
    cin >> y;
    z = (mathFunc(2, x) + mathFunc(2.7, y)) / abs(mathFunc(b+2, (x+y)));
    cout << "Результат z = " << z;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
double mathFunc(double a, double v)
{
    return log(v)/log(a)
}
```

Comment: а модуль все таки fabs же нужен, если не ошибаюсь

Comment: Вы вслед за ТС решили считать логарифм натуральный как по основанию 2.7, а по основанию 2 *не* как `log2`?... У него в примере нестандартный логарифм единственный - зачем вообще его оформлять функцией?...

Comment: fabs - это сишное. Там перегрузка функций долгое время только так и работала. @Harry - ну задание такое. В институте/университете нужно один-два раза написать самому даже сортировку, что бы понимать как оно работает. А потом использовать готовые функции.

Comment: Всем спасибо. Всем респект.

Comment: Я неправильно что-то понял? У вас ведь логарифм от логарифма вычисляется? Например, в `log(mathFunc(2, x)`?

Comment: возможно. я просто легко пофиксил код.